# Unable to Install Latest SCIDvsPC

Tags: chess

I have installed the latest SCID package (1:4.7.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu2) from Ubuntu via Synaptic. However, when I open SCID I still see the old UI (Help >> About shows version 4.19).

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Entering `type -a scid` shows two lines:

```
scid is /usr/local/bin/scid  
scid is /usr/games/scid
```

I can get the new version by entering `/usr/games/scid` at the bash prompt. I'd like to have the Icon point to that version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? What does `type -a scid` show?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Entering type -a scid shows two lines:  scid is /usr/local/bin/scid and
scid is /usr/games/scid

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. Until you [edit] your question to add the new info, I will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find which package provides the two `scid` executables with

```
 dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/scid
 dpkg -S /usr/games/scid
```

and `sudo apt uninstall` the package you don't want.